# What executes markdown cell in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter Notebook, I know the python kernel executes the content in a code cell, while I wonder what kernel or something executes markdown cell?

Answer (score 0):

Markdown isn't a programming language so it doesn't need a kernel to execute it, it is instead rendered. It essentially needs to be converted to HTML. The Jupyter Notebook renders it itself (unlike the kernel, which is run as a separate process) using [marked](https://marked.js.org/)